# My Contact field does not do anything when I change the top field

Tags: html, css

```css
.contact-form {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 30px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000b3;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}


/* This is the css */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contact-form">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <div class="txtb">
      <label>Full Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
      <label>Email :</label>
      <input type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
      <label>Phone Number :</label>
      <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
    </div>

    <a class="btn">Send</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

My Problem is that even though i have the top: 50%, it does not center vertically
but the left: 50% makes it centered horizontally so I am confused as to why the top isn't working.
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: The form looks center vertically now

Comment: The code you provided should align `div` center vertically and horizontally. Unless check with parent CSS. Something must be wrong there.

Comment: @YuvaneshAnand  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether you liked my suggestion or do I need to ameliorate my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code and it is aligned in center from left and top both.

I have a suggestion for you that next time you code try using **vw** instead of **%**, it will help you to make your webpage/website more responsive.